# Running Cypress in Jenkins CI fails to find browser executable

Tags: typescript, jenkins, testing, cypress

I tried to use Cypress in a Jenkins-pipeline

Currently there is a Agent running in an dedecated Win-PC with the user for the Jenkins-job

If I run Cypress over remote-desktop there is no problem, but if I try to run the same command with a jenkins-pipeline then Cypress cant find any browser.

The pipeline is like

- checkout git
- npm ci
- npx cypress run ...

Cypress info from jenkins-pipeline:

```
C:\...\path>npx cypress info 


Proxy Settings: none detected
Environment Variables: none detected

Application Data: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Roaming\cypress\cy\development
Browser Profiles: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Roaming\cypress\cy\development\browsers
Binary Caches: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache

Cypress Version: 12.8.1 (stable)
System Platform: win32 (10.0.19043)
System Memory: 34.1 GB free 26.6 GB
```

Cypress info from remote-cmd:

```
C:\...\path>npx cypress info 

Displaying Cypress info...

Detected 3 browsers installed:

1. Chrome
  - Name: chrome
  - Channel: stable
  - Version: 114.0.5735.90
  - Executable: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

2. Edge
  - Name: edge
  - Channel: stable
  - Version: 114.0.1823.37
  - Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe

3. Firefox
  - Name: firefox
  - Channel: stable
  - Version: 113.0.2
  - Executable: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
  - Profile: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy\production\browsers\firefox-stable

Note: to run these browsers, pass <name>:<channel> to the '--browser' field

Examples:
- cypress run --browser edge
- cypress run --browser firefox

Learn More: https://on.cypress.io/launching-browsers

Proxy Settings: none detected
Environment Variables: none detected

Application Data: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Roaming\cypress\cy\development
Browser Profiles: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Roaming\cypress\cy\development\browsers
Binary Caches: C:\Users\sebuild\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache

Cypress Version: 12.8.1 (stable)
System Platform: win32 (10.0.19043)
System Memory: 34.1 GB free 26.8 GB
```

#### Cypress Version

12.8.1
Also testet on v12.13.0 and same result

#### Node version

16.18.0

#### Operating System

Windows 10.0.19044.2965

#### Debug Logs

There are no logs when I try to run cypress with this command:

```bash
C:\...\path>npx cypress run --browser firefox --spec ./path/to/test.spec.ts --env="IMPORTANT_ENVS=set"
```

#### Other

Also tested with default cypress.config.ts, same result